How to pass SQL fields into Logic Power App Emal ( When an item is created (v2) )
I have new project which involves connecting Dynamics 365 to an Azure Managed SQL instance.
There is a team setting up Dynamics initially however the data task is under my remit.
I have been recommended to use a logic app to pass information such as registrations to Dynamics to be managed as leads.
I have setup my first logic app, which is very simple:
When an item is created v2 -> Send an email v2
This proves that the SQL connection is working as the email generates.
Now the next step, is that I would like to pull information into that email, I will start with COMPANYNAME & ORGANISATIONGUID which is created by the form and input into the SQL table.
I cannot see a way to pull dynamic / SQL information into the the email
I pretense this with I am an IT body who has moved into PowerBI / SQL over the last 2 years, so am not a developer but do understand the basics
Some searching has shown in older versions of logic apps there is a 'dynamic' button however I cannot see that on my version:
Send email v2

I found the answer to this, if you hover your mouse over the left side of the email body area, a functions button appears which you can then add to the body.
enter image description here
